# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException?

Tags: php, laravel

I am following with laracast and have reached a part I cannot figure out. When trying to display a title `{{$blog->title}}` I get the following error:

> Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: /Users/***/Desktop/DigitalCulture/DG/resources/views/blogs/show.blade.php)"

Database:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('excerpt');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/about', function () {
    $blogs = DB::table('blogs')->take(3)->latest()->get();

    return view('/about', [
        'blogs' => $blogs
    ]);
});

Route::get('/blogs/{blog}', 'BlogsController@show');
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\blog;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BlogsController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {

        $blog = Blog::find($id);

        if( is_null($blog) ){
            dd( 'There is no post with this id='.$id);
        }

        return view('blogs.show')->with('blog', $blog);
    }
}
```

Show.blade

```
@extends ('layout')

@section ('content')

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page" class="container">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="title">
                <h2> {{$blog->title}} </h2>
                </div>

            <p><img src="/images/banner.jpg" alt="" class="image image-full" /> </p>
            <p> 
            {{$blog->body}}
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
@endsection
```

Blog PHP

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    //
}
```

DATABASE

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/yswTb.png][1]

Comment: Could you add your Blog model class ?

Comment: Sure... added it in the original post

Comment: did you make sure that our file name is Blog.php with Capital B

Comment: Yes, its Blog.php with a capital B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a silly issue, becuase I created two posts with $id 1 and 2, it was looking for those specific ids. Once I entered the correct url with the $id of 1 or 2 it found the 'title' id in the blog.

Answer (score 0):

Update

```php
public function show($id)  {
```

to

```php
public function show(Blog $blog) {
```

Comment: Results in a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all of your `blogs` have `title` property? Seems like some blogs are missing it. If that's the case, you can use some [ternary](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/even-shorter-ternary-operators-in-php-using/) operators in your blade, to check if data exists, so you don't get an exception. Simple example:

```
{{$blog->title ? $blog->title : 'No title' }}
```

Answer (score -1):

First you have to edit this line `use App\blog;` to `use App\Blog;` then try to share the variable like that `return view('blogs.show', compact('blog'));` or `return view('blogs.show', ['blog' => $blog]);`

Comment: You mean `compact` instead of composer ?

Comment: When I change this line App\blog; to App\Blog I get a syntax error T_USE.

Comment: Yes i mean `compact` sorry for this mistake i just edited the answer .. About syntax error T_use check if you already put `;` like that `use App\Blog;` and it depend on your name of `model` class.

Answer (score -1):

You may use

**[Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BlogsController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $blog = DB::table('blogs')->find($id);

        if($blog){
            return view('blogs.show')->with('blog', $blog);
        }
        dd( 'There is no post with this id='.$id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found when I use this code.

Comment: @PT-83 Add this line in the top of your BlogController.php : 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; 
And check updated answer

Comment: I get the dd 'there is no post with this id".

Comment: Hi @Foued MOUSSI yes, I've added a link (screenshot) in the original post showing my database on tableplus.  Let me know if something stands out.